# Will this drill bit work on concrete?

Tags: concrete, drill

I'm very new at drilling stuff and I have never drilled a hole in my life before. I need to drill through concrete (I don't know what kind of concrete it is), and I'm wondering if the following drill bit is good for the task.

http://www.homedepot.ca/product/sds-plus-hammer-carbide-5-32-in-x-2-in-x-4-in/975357

Also, will the type of hand drill matter when you are drilling through concrete?

Comment: How deep, how many holes, and for what purpose?

Comment: @Bryce three holes, at least good 3 inches (I think), and it's for an air conditioner mounting bracket

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely that will drill through concrete but you will need a SDS hammer drill which the typical home owner does not have. This is the type of drill http://www.jccayer.com/product.php?productid=1169

For such a small hole you can use a regular rotary pistol grip hammer drill with a cheap Canadian tire masonry bit to do your holes.

Comment: You can rent hammer drills, not sure if the rental comes with a bit or they make you buy that separate. For smaller masonry holes (5/32" would be small for me), you can get a higher end cordless drill with a hammer setting.

Comment: He'll need an SDS **Plus** hammer drill. The [SDS shank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drill_bit_shank#SDS_shank) comes in 4 configurations.

Comment: Renting makes sense for the really big stuff, but i'm not sure it makes sense for a basic SDS+ hammer drill. When I look where I live, I can pick up an own-brand corded SDS+ Hammer drill for £50.

Answer (score 3):

For a couple of holes that are less than 1/4", I'd try a cordless drill with a hammer setting. I've got this [DeWalt](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000X1S0LC) in my personal collection. When you start doing a lot of holes, get in the 1/2" or larger size, particularly if they are fairly deep and the concrete is very dense, then I'd rent a higher end corded power tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you have just a few holes, you're better off with something like the Vermont American 14014 rotary 5/32" bit, which can drill 2" deep.  It will be somewhat slower than the SDS and hammer drill bits, but you can use a regular rotary drill.  Just take your time, and blow out the dust periodically.